# trouble with opencv3 install

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am using anaconda to install opencv3 for my python 3.6.1 under mac os.

however, I got the following return:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - opencv3 -> python 2.7* -> openssl 1.0.1*
  - python 3.6*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: try `conda install python=3.5` `conda install -c  opencv3`

Answer (score 0):

I was just trying to get opencv working and I was having the exact same issue,
resolved using python3.5 and opencv3 instead
==>

`conda install python=3.5`

then

`conda install -c menpo opencv3`